# ListView have only one item

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that is showing only one item instead of two.
thats my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView Add;
ImageView Shadow;
ProgressBar PB;

ListView listView;
String[] valuesUp = { "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "Sed non justo eros. Praesent a nisl dui" };
String[] valuesDown = { "Quisque ut ante eu arcu sagittis porta eu a dolor...",
        "In orci augue facilisis eget fermentum consequat ac..." };
int[] imgValues = {R.drawable.mobileapp_16, R.drawable.mobileapp_19};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAdapter(this, valuesUp, valuesDown, imgValues);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and thats my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] valuesUp;
private final String[] valuesDown;
private final int[] ImageValue;
private TextView textViewUp;
private TextView textViewDown;
private ImageView image;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] valuesUP, String[] valuesDown, int[] imageValue) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, valuesUP);
    this.context = context;
    this.valuesUp = valuesUP;
    this.valuesDown = valuesDown;
    this.ImageValue = imageValue;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    textViewUp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view_up);
    textViewDown = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view_down);
    image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    textViewUp.setText(valuesUp[position]);
    textViewDown.setText(valuesDown[position]);
    image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(ImageValue[position]));

    return rowView;
}}
```

When I debug I see that the getView is getting called a lot of times (about 12) and all of the time the "position" is 0. Why is That?
Thanks!

I found my problem now! Its weird. the height of the list is acting weird. when I am doing "wrap_content or match_parent it gives me one item but when for example I a puting 400dp its ok.  why is that?!
Thats my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/progress"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar_bg" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar_leftcircle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar_logo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar_menu" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar_key" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/mobileapp_14" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/transparent_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Sed at vestibulum elit. Nunc quam erat, gravida ac consequat"
            android:textColor="@color/RedText"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Nullam sed erat erat, ut faucibus nunc. Etiam et mi di ante lacinia suscipit. Mauris gravida turpis eget lectus ullam..."
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/mobileapp_15" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView7" >

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you please share your layouts also?

Comment: Its a very long layout.  it has a simple list item in it.

Comment: Have you set the height of list view as wrapContent or match_parent?

Comment: post your xml here and also post the row.xml

Answer (score 2):

@roiberg 
your code is working fine in my emulator.
Check your XML code

Answer (score 2):

I have found you problem.

Your problem is in XML.

Delete the **ScrollView** from the xml . The problem will solved.

Comment: but i need is to scroll...  I want the whole page to scroll. the list itself is not scrollable.

Comment: You can't put ListView with in a ScrollView. Because ListView can scroll itself.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't keep the height of listView as wrap_content as this is very expensive.
Give it as fill_parent/match_parent and give a try.

Giving wrap_content will make the system do a lot of operations to calculate the height of listView. This will give multiple calls to item at position 0.

You should not give ListView inside a scrollView. This never works!

Comment: Usually a scrollable item should not come come inside another scrollablle view. This will lead to performance issues.

Comment: but thats not my problem, the list is not scrollable... also, why is it not showing the whole list?!

Comment: When you put a listView inside a scrollview, the scroll of both these views get screwed up. Romain Guy- the developer of ListView explains about these things here: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: Thank you, but there exist aplication that have a scroll bar with list in it.

Comment: There is a workaround to get it done. Use the method mentioned here:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm

Answer (score 0):

Change you Activity like this

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView Add;
    ImageView Shadow;
    ProgressBar PB;

```
ListView listView;
String[] valuesUp = { "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
"Sed non justo eros. Praesent a nisl dui" };
String[] valuesDown = { "Quisque ut ante eu arcu sagittis porta eu a dolor...",
"In orci augue facilisis eget fermentum consequat ac..." };
int[] imgValues = {R.drawable.mobileapp_16, R.drawable.mobileapp_19};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,valuesUp,valuesDown,imgValues));
}
```

Change the Adapter like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context context;
private final String[] valuesUp;
private final String[] valuesDown;
private final int[] ImageValue;
private TextView textViewUp;
private TextView textViewDown;
private ImageView image;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] valuesUP, String[] valuesDown, int[] imageValue) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, valuesUP);
    this.context = context;
    this.valuesUp = valuesUP;
    this.valuesDown = valuesDown;
    this.ImageValue = imageValue;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    textViewUp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view_up);
    textViewDown = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view_down);
    image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    textViewUp.setText(valuesUp[position]);
    textViewDown.setText(valuesDown[position]);
    image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(ImageValue[position]));

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return valuesUp.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return valuesUp[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still doing the same problem...  position is still always 0 and getItemId is never called.

Comment: are u getting two items in it

Comment: in what? I still have only one item in the list at the end.

Comment: can u post ur output image how it looks for me its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
I placed the first images in a stand alone layout and made this layout the first cell in the list.
so, now i have the images and the list itself as one big scrollable list.
If someone see any big problem with this I would like to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because I was using **NestedScrollView** so the solution was add  **android:fillViewport="true"** to my NestedScrollView

Here my code:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```